# Why is handlebars not working in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have written the line:

`app.engine('hbs',hbs({extanme:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}));`

And I have assigned:

`var hbs= require('handlebars');`

The error I get is:

> hbs  is not a function

Comment: Let's assign hbs value before using it.

Comment: share your app.js

Comment: if it helped you, an upvote or acceptance as answer would help others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
npm i hbs // install hbs package

//app.js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const hbs = require('hbs')
const app = express()

// View Engine Setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('Home', {
    array: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'],
    message: 'Greetings from geekforgeeks'
    })
})

app.listen(8080, function(error){
    if(error) throw error
    console.log("Server created Successfully")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For your app.engine after referencing the NPM express-handlebar docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars. You need to add a .engine to your hbs constant.

try this!

```
var hbs= require('handlebars');

app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine('your config stuff here'));
```

If your still running into issues. Try using express-handlebars (*npm install express express-handlebars)* with express, then require them like you do. Then it should work

Answer (score 0):

**Try This!!**

*Add hbs.engine*

```
app.engine('hbs',hbs.engine({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}));
```

**And assign:**
var hbs= require('express-handlebars');